# convert WAV to ALAC

Tags: iphone, wav, audioformat

Can we convert from WAV format to apple's ALAC audio recording format ?

Answer (score 0):

See the ConvertFile sample project: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/ConvertFile/Introduction/Intro.html